# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans

I am new with J2EE and Hibernate
Please help me to solve this problem, I can't find a solution for it

this is my code :

```
package inventory.service.user;

import inventory.domain.User;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


public class Authentication {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @NotEmpty
    private String login;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    private String error;

    public User getUser(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(password);
        return user;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login){ 
        this.login = login; 
        logger.info("Authentication: login set to "+ login);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){ 
        this.password = password;
        logger.info("Authentication: password set to "+ password);
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

I work in netBeans IDE, and I added these jar's files

> aopalliance
>
> aspectjweaver
>
> derbyclient
>
> hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final
>
> hibernate-search-5.3.0.Beta2-dist
>
> jstl-1.2
>
> org-netbeans-modules-web-jstl11.jar

the message error is :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
root cause
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

Comment: Did you look in the stack trace to try to determine what class wasn't found?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051267/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-documentexception