# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DocumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot with spring security application, i am getting below exception while starting the application

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DocumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:151) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Which jar is missed?

Comment: Seems very similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051267/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-documentexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051267/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-documentexception)

Answer (score 0):

dom4j.jar seems to be missing. Try adding that into the classpath.